# cannot get the option to start up windows xp

Tags: windows-xp

i installed ubuntu 13.04 on a pc with windows xp already installed. I can see my windows files in the file manager but do not get an option to boot into windows xp. i need to use visual studio otherwise this would not be a problem. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

**[Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)** is a simple tool to repair frequent boot issues you may encounter in Ubuntu like when you can't boot Ubuntu after installing Windows or another Linux distribution, or when you can't boot Windows after installing Ubuntu, or when GRUB is not displayed anymore, some upgrade breaks GRUB, etc.

To install it, open a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Terminal), and run next commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

Comment: Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @Malachy Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem!

Comment: @duxk.gh You are invited in room chat [Discussion between Radu and duxk.gh](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8811/discussion-between-radu-and-duxk-gh).